# Hash table with collision lists printing error

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable

I have hash-table with collision list (as linked list) and the program crash when i run it. I think the problem is in display() function that print all the values stored in one list with assigned key, maybe some pointers problem. I appreciate your help guys.

```
struct node {
        long key;
        long long int data1,data2;
        struct node *next;
  };


  struct hash {
        struct node *head;
        int count;
  };

  struct hash *hashTable = NULL;

  struct node * createNode(long key, long long int data1,long long int data2) {
        struct node *newnode;
        newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        newnode->key = key;
        newnode->data1 = data1;
        newnode->data2 = data2;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        return newnode;
  }

void insertToHash(int key, long long int data1,long long int data2) {
        int hashIndex = key % eleCount;
        struct node *newnode =  createNode(key, data1, data2);
        if (!hashTable[hashIndex].head) {
                hashTable[hashIndex].head = newnode;
                hashTable[hashIndex].count = 1;
                return;
        }
        newnode->next = (hashTable[hashIndex].head);
        hashTable[hashIndex].head = newnode;
        hashTable[hashIndex].count++;
        return;
  }


void display(long key)  
{  
  struct node *cur_ptr;  
  long hashIndex = key % eleCount;

  cur_ptr=hashTable[hashIndex].head; 

  if(cur_ptr==NULL)  
  {  
     printf("\nList is Empty");  
  }  
  else  
  {  
      printf("\nElements in the List: ");  
      while(cur_ptr!=NULL)  
      {  
          printf("Key  : %lx , ", cur_ptr->key);
          printf("Pairs: (%llx,%llx)\n", cur_ptr->data1,cur_ptr->data2);
          cur_ptr=cur_ptr->next;  
      }  
      printf("\n");  
  }  
} 

   int main(void) {
        hashTable = (struct hash *)calloc(10, sizeof (struct hash));
        insertToHash(0xc767c053L,0x779d5a063fae2e7dLL,0x22499ae36fc6291fLL);
        insertToHash(0xc767c053L,0x2cf969e8a45cb021LL,0x198d9cca0f803198LL);
        insertToHash(0xf71a12d9L,0xde48739df8ab07fdLL,0x29902869a0887968LL);
        display(0xc767c053L);          
        return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Try the debugger. Good thing to learn about

Comment: What is 'eleCount' init'ed to? It should be 10. You almost have a compilable example, see http://sscce.org/. Also, what did valgrind tell you?

Comment: @CharlieBurns yes eleCount=10 and it's a global variable.

Comment: @EdHeal segmentation fault in display()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hashIndex is going negative. This:

```
void insertToHash(int key, long long int data1,long long int data2) {
        int hashIndex = key % eleCount;
```

Should be

```
void insertToHash(long key, long long int data1,long long int data2) {
        int hashIndex = key % eleCount;
```

Also, always check the return from malloc/calloc.

You will save time in the long run if you learn how to effective with gdb and valgrind.

Comment: i know that the index going negative but it's not a problem for the purposes of the program.

Comment: I love it when you guys say, "that's not the problem"! Let me know when you discover it actually is a problem! There's an expression, "you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink".

Comment: How well is "if (!hashTable[-7].head)" going to work?

Comment: you're right with the positive index everything work. Thank you.